# Почему мой вопрос хотят закрыть?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Собственно, задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647840/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-vega/647855#647855). Через некоторое время нашёл на него ответ. Мой вопрос хотят закрыть именно из-за этого? Его стоит удалить?

Comment: два голоса закрытия за пункт: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей._ Что, в принципе, логично - в вопросе говорится что что-то не работает, но что не работает, как не работает и почему вообще подумал что не работает - не рассказано.

Comment: @Grundy Стоит ли производить действия над таким вопросом уже после того, как дан ответ: удалить, подправить или иное?